# How do i prevent other Visual Studio Online team members from reassigning tasks?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have created a Visual Studio Online project and added some team members, I have added some features and user stories and I have also assigned them to the members. My problem is the members are able to reassign the tasks to other members and move the boards of other members to a different status.Is there any specific policy that can help me achieve this?

Comment: Do you clear it?

Answer (score 0):

No. Either someone can modify work items under a given area path, or they cannot.